# How do extensions like "React developer tools" work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

I am trying to build a chrome dev-tool which would help developers debug their code (javascript code in frontend). But since most developers use tools like webpack to build their javascript code into a single large file and the code that the browser gets doesn't look like what they've written at development time, I want to know if there is a way to access the code they've written. Is this the way how tools like react-devtools detect React app and provide external stuff based on that code? If yes, how so?

Answer (score 1):

[JS Sourcemaps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) might be handy if this is what you're trying to achieve.